# How can I convert docx to doc using Python?

Tags: python, docx, doc, file-conversion

How can I convert file.docx to file.doc using Python? I have a code that outputs a file in docx format, but this program is for someone who can only use Word 2003, so I need to convert that file to .doc using Python. How can I do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know of any utilities that could directly convert from docx to doc, but you can use the package `docx2pdf` and convert that into a pdf, and then convert back to a document, using the `os` package by specifying the `.doc` extension. Hint: os.write()

Answer (score 1):

Bit clunky, but you could use pywinauto to programatically open your .docx documents in word, then save-as .doc. It'd be using word to do the conversion, so it should be as clean as you could get.

This is a snippet of what I've used for converting to pdf within word (it was just a test). You'd have to follow the keystrokes necessary to save as a .doc

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto.application import Application


app1 = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE")
wordhndl = app1.top_window()


wordhndl.type_keys('^o')
wordhndl.type_keys('%f')
wordhndl.type_keys('^o')
wordhndl.type_keys('^o')

#Now that we're in a sub-window, using the top_window() handle doesn't work...
#Instead refer to absolute (using friendly_class_name())
app1.Dialog.Open.type_keys("Y:\\996.Software\\04.Python\\Test\\SampleDoc1.docx")
app1.Dialog.Open.type_keys('~')


#Publish it to pdf
app1.SampleDoc1docx.type_keys('%f')
app1.SampleDoc1docx.type_keys('e')
app1.SampleDoc1docx.type_keys('p')
app1.SampleDoc1docx.type_keys('a')
app1.SampleDoc1docx.PublishasPDForXPS.Publish.type_keys('~')


#Deal with popups & prompts
if app1.Dialog.PublishasPDForXPS.ConfirmSaveAs.exists():
    app1.Dialog.PublishasPDForXPS.ConfirmSaveAs.Yes.click()  #This line can take some time...
```

I think the .doc keystrokes would be (not tested)

```
app1.SampleDoc1docx.type_keys('%f')
app1.SampleDoc1docx.type_keys('a')
app1.SampleDoc1docx.type_keys('y')
app1.SampleDoc1docx.type_keys('4')
app1.SampleDoc1docx.type_keys('{DOWN}')
app1.SampleDoc1docx.type_keys('{DOWN}')
app1.SampleDoc1docx.type_keys('~')
app1.SampleDoc1docx.type_keys('{RIGHT}')
app1.SampleDoc1docx.type_keys('~')
```

But... the better solution is to use word. I've used VBA within word to do this exact thing before. Don't have the code to hand, but a good pointer would be:
https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/3-quick-ways-to-batch-convert-word-doc-to-docx-files-and-vice-versa/

Answer (score 0):

you can do something of the likes of:

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document("myWordxFile.docx")
doc.save('myNewWordFile.doc')
```

check [this](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx) too. Good luck!